# in iOS, does VC stay alive for a short time after VC is pop'ed out of navigation controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am having a likely race condition issue:

in UIViewController, I have created a scheduler based on NSTimer. The implementation of scheduler is this:

```
public final class SwiftSimpleScheduler {
  
  private enum TimerState {
    case normal
    case paused(remaining: TimeInterval)
  }
  
  private struct TimerInfo {
    let timer: Timer
    let state: TimerState
  }
  
  private var keyToTimerInfoMap = [String:TimerInfo]()

  public init() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(pause), name:UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(resume), name:UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
  }
  
  deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    for (_, info) in keyToTimerInfoMap {
      info.timer.invalidate()
    }
  }
  
  @objc
  public func pause() {
    for (key, info) in keyToTimerInfoMap {
      switch info.state {
      case .normal:
        let remaining = info.timer.fireDate.timeIntervalSinceNow
        info.timer.fireDate = Date.distantFuture
        keyToTimerInfoMap[key] = TimerInfo(timer: info.timer, state: .paused(remaining: remaining))
      case .paused:
        break
      }
    }
  }
  
  @objc
  public func resume() {
    for (key, info) in keyToTimerInfoMap {
      switch info.state {
      case .normal:
        break
      case .paused(let remaining):
        info.timer.fireDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: remaining)
        keyToTimerInfoMap[key] = TimerInfo(timer: info.timer, state: .normal)
      }
    }
  }
  
  private func schedule(key: String, interval: Double, repeats: Bool, callImmediately: Bool, block: @escaping ((_ key: String) -> Void)) -> String {

    if callImmediately {
      block(key)
    }
    
    let timerBlock: (Timer) -> Void = { [weak self] timer in
      guard let ss = self else { return }
      block(key)
      if !repeats {
        ss.keyToTimerInfoMap.removeValue(forKey: key)
      }
    }
    let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(
      withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(interval),
      repeats: repeats,
      block: timerBlock)
    
    keyToTimerInfoMap[key] = TimerInfo(
      timer: timer,
      state: .normal)
    
    return key
  }
  
  private func unschedule(key: String) {
    guard let info = keyToTimerInfoMap[key] else { return }
    info.timer.invalidate()
    keyToTimerInfoMap.removeValue(forKey: key)
  }

    
  private func getRandomKey() -> String {
    return UUID().uuidString
  }
  
  private func getKeyWith(_ target: NSObjectProtocol, selector: Selector) -> String {
    return "\(target.hash) - \(selector.hashValue)"
  }
}

// MARK: - Target action API

public extension SwiftSimpleScheduler {
  
  func scheduleOnce(after delay: Double, target: NSObjectProtocol, selector: Selector) {
    _ = schedule(
      key: getKeyWith(target, selector: selector),
      interval: delay,
      repeats: false,
      callImmediately: false)
    { [weak target, weak self] _ in
      guard let target = target, let ss = self else { return }
      UIApplication.shared.sendAction(selector, to: target, from: ss, for: nil)
    }
  }
  
  func scheduleEvery(_ interval: Double, callImmediately: Bool, target: NSObjectProtocol, selector: Selector) {
    _ = schedule(
      key: getKeyWith(target, selector: selector),
      interval: interval,
      repeats: true,
      callImmediately: callImmediately)
    { [weak target, weak self] _ in
      guard let target = target, let ss = self else { return }
      UIApplication.shared.sendAction(selector, to: target, from: ss, for: nil)
    }
  }
  
  func unscheduleTarget(_ target: NSObjectProtocol, selector: Selector) {
    unschedule(key: getKeyWith(target, selector: selector))
  }
}

// MARK: - closure API

extension SwiftSimpleScheduler {
    
  public func scheduleOnce(after delay: Double, block: @escaping (() -> Void)) -> String {
    return schedule(
      key: getRandomKey(),
      interval: delay,
      repeats: false,
      callImmediately: false) { _ in
      block()
    }
  }

  public func scheduleEvery(_ interval: Double, callImmediately: Bool, block: @escaping ((String) -> Void)) -> String {
    return schedule(
      key: getRandomKey(),
      interval: interval,
      repeats: true,
      callImmediately: callImmediately) { s in
      block(s)
    }
  }

  public func unscheduleBlock(forKey key: String) {
    unschedule(key: key)
  }

}
```

Then in VC's viewDidLoad:

```
class GameVC: UIViewController {
  public let scheduler = SwiftSimpleScheduler()
  ... 

  scheduler.scheduleEvery(1, callImmediately: false, target: self, selector: #selector(onTick))

  @objc
  func onTick() {
    // crash here, CURRENT_GAME_VC is nil
    aFunctionThatTakesNonOptionalVC(CURRENT_GAME_VC)
  }
```

Then in `onTick`, I accessed this forced unwrapped property:

```
public var CURRENT_GAME_VC: GameVC! {
  for vc in NAV_VC?.viewControllers ?? [] {
    if let gameVC = vc as? GameVC {
      return gameVC
    }
  }
  return nil
}
```

This crashed sometimes, but I wasn't able to reproduce (I only get the crash report from Firebase analytics from real users. It happened very very rarely (less than 1% of users). So I suspect that this is due to race condition.

When VC is dealocated, the scheduler property of VC must be deallocated, which calls the scheduler's `deinit`, which deactivated the timer, so that crash shouldn't happen after deallocation.

Is it possible that the `GameVC` is pop'ed off the nav stack, but `GameVC` is not de-allocated, resulting in the next `onTick` still getting called?

Edit:

The above code is simplified version. In actual code, my `onTick` function calls a few other functions, and eventually call a function `didUpdateState`, which access this forced unwrap property.

Firebase doesn't give me the crash reason. Luckily, the `didUpdateState` function only contains 1 line, so I was able to identify that it's because of `CURRENT_GAME_VC` being nil.

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  GPLNum                         0x12310 MenuBar.didUpdateState(_:delta:isInitial:) + 15760 (MenuBar.swift:15760)
1  GPLNum                         0x12584 vtable thunk for CommonGameRegion.didUpdateState(_:delta:isInitial:) dispatching to MenuBar.didUpdateState(_:delta:isInitial:) + 16388 (<compiler-generated>:16388)
2  LibGame                        0x361c8 CommonGameScene.helper_callDidUpdateState(_:delta:isInitial:) + 19652 (<compiler-generated>:19652)
3  LibGame                        0x3796c partial apply for closure #1 in CommonGameScene.init(preloadResources:state:commonInfo:levelType:supportsRating:pushables:regions:scnScene:) + 25704 (<compiler-generated>:25704)
4  LibApp                         0x67a64 partial apply for thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed (@in_guaranteed A, @in_guaranteed B?) -> () + 20044 (<compiler-generated>:20044)
5  LibApp                         0x6740c StateStore.notify(delta:) + 18420 (<compiler-generated>:18420)
6  LibApp                         0x672ac StateStore.updateAndNotify(_:) + 27 (StateStore.swift:27)
7  GPLNum                         0xfda4 @objc GameScene.onTick() + 6180 (<compiler-generated>:6180)
8  UIKitCore                      0x24ed34 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 100
9  LibApp                         0x4b478 specialized closure #1 in SwiftSimpleScheduler.scheduleEvery(_:callImmediately:target:selector:) + 916
10 LibApp                         0x49a8c closure #1 in SwiftSimpleScheduler.schedule(key:interval:repeats:callImmediately:block:) + 75 (SwiftSimpleScheduler.swift:75)
11 LibApp                         0x49b28 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed @Sendable (@guaranteed NSTimer) -> () + 5116 (<compiler-generated>:5116)
12 Foundation                     0x835f8 __NSFireTimer + 96
13 CoreFoundation                 0xce35c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
14 CoreFoundation                 0x8a9d8 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 940
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2e598 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 288
16 CoreFoundation                 0x7bfcc __CFRunLoopRun + 1896
17 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612
18 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal + 164
19 UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
20 UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain + 340
21 libswiftUIKit.dylib            0x35308 UIApplicationMain(_:_:_:_:) + 104
22 BinMinesweeper                 0x705c main + 4307300444 (AppSceneDelegate.swift:4307300444)
23 ???                            0x1d6204960 (Missing)
```

Edit 2: In production code, scheduler actually lives in a SKScene, rather than UIViewController. But I don't think it's relevant. I simply add the scene to an `SKView`. So for simplicity, in the snippet, I put the code in `GameVC` rather than `GameScene`.

Comment: I would refactor to eliminate the invocation of selectors and simply pass a closure to be invoked to your `scheduleEvery`. Not only is it more "swifty" but you avoid the risk of selector invocation against a potentially deallocated object.

Comment: Sometimes it's more convenient to use `target/action`. I often have an action that is too long, so I would end up calling `self?.aHelperFunction()` inside the closure anyways.

Comment: Calling `self?.aHelperFunction` is safer than invoking a selector too. What is the exception message you are getting.  Selectors are Objective-C, so it is also dragging ObjC compliance into this

Comment: The actual crash is a bit complicated. The `onTick` actually calls multiple functions and eventually call something that only access this forced unwrapped property.

Comment: let me add the crash log from firebase

Comment: btw, for the scheduler I actually do have a closure API as well. I updated the code snippet the full scheduler class. Though that's likely not relevant. But just in case.

Comment: From the stack trace it appears to have crashed in MenuBar.didUpdateState. What is the exception message?

Comment: Yes, the `didUpdateState` has only 1 line that calls a function that takes a non-optional VC. However, there's no crash message on Firebase and I don't know why :(

Comment: At the minimum, do not force unwrap, especially since you are explicitly returning a nil here - return optional instead. On usage, unwrap and consider the state where CURRENT_GAME_VC is nil as some terminator of the current work (i.e. you may need to continue when it happened).

Comment: But on larger scale... IMO this code needs refactoring. Right now VC holds scheduler, which operates on VC, which owns scheduler lifecycle... Instead create some clear one way dependency, i.e. either VC owns scheduler (and scheduler knows nothing about VC, except for an optional weak callback it needs to invoke in some situations). Or scheduler operates as if it has many of such VCs, and thus it will be responsible for checking if they are still valid / schedule next operation and so on

Comment: Yeah i have seen many patterns that early returns when VC is nil (e.g. `guard let self = self`). However, in this particular case, I was hoping that the callback is not even called.

Comment: Thinking about it again - is it possible that the target/action API is invoked 1 frame after it's been sent? (`UIApplication.shared.sendAction(selector, to: target, from: ss, for: nil)`). After calling `sendAction`, the VC happens to get popped out of nav stack and get deallocated, and then the target/action is triggered, causing the race condition? If that's the case, I may have to keep the closure API and remove target/action API @Paulw11 @klangfarb

Comment: NVM, i just did a quick experiment - target/action API is synchronous - after `sendAction` is called, the selector is called immediately

Comment: In `GameVC`, do you ever call one of the `unscheduleXXX` methods? That really should be done to ensure this problem doesn't happen. Also, why doesn't `CURRENT_GAME_VC` return an optional? Using an implicitly unwrapped optional return value with a `return nil` is just asking for trouble. `onTick` can easily avoid calling `aFunctionThatTakesNonOptionalVC` if `CURRENT_GAME_VC` returns `nil`.

Comment: @HangarRash it does not call unscheduleXXX, however, the `deinit` will be called.

Comment: I understand that making `CURRENT_GAME_VC` non-optional will fix the crash, but it may hide the bug actually, because the function shouldn't even be called - when vc is pop'ed, the scheduler's deinit should be called.

Answer (score 0):

Invalidate the timer on viewDidDisappear(_:) or custom back button action.